# LibGdx actor bounds incorrect

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a simple game and faced with a problem. My virtual screen size is 640x360, but if I launch my game on device with, for example 1920x1080 screen resolution, actors' bouns stay in my virtual world coordinates, but not in 1920x1080, so I can't detect any input. Can anyone help me?

```
private Stage stage;

private Preferences SoundPrefs;

private Texture TitleTexture, PlayTexture, BallsTexture, RatingsTexture, ShopTexture, NoadsTexture, SoundOnTexture, SoundOffTexture;

private MenuTextureActor Title, Play, Balls, Ratings, Shop, Noads, Sound;

public MenuScreen(MainGame gam) {
    super(gam);
    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(640, 360));
    SoundPrefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Sound");
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            if (screenX >= Play.getX() && screenY >= Play.getY() && screenX <= (Play.getX() + Play.getWidth())
                    && screenY <= (Play.getY() + Play.getHeight())) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
            }
            if (screenX >= Sound.getX() && screenY >= Sound.getY() && screenX <= (Sound.getX() + Sound.getWidth())
                    && screenY <= (Sound.getY() + Sound.getHeight())){
                if (SoundPrefs.getBoolean("Sound", true) == true){
                    SoundPrefs.putBoolean("Sound", false);
                    Sound.ChangeTexture(SoundOffTexture);
                } else if (SoundPrefs.getBoolean("Sound", true) == false) {
                    SoundPrefs.putBoolean("Sound", true);
                    Sound.ChangeTexture(SoundOnTexture);
                }
                SoundPrefs.flush();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void show() {
    TitleTexture = game.getManager().get("title.png");
    TitleTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    PlayTexture = game.getManager().get("play.png");
    PlayTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    BallsTexture = game.getManager().get("balls.png");
    BallsTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    RatingsTexture = game.getManager().get("ratings.png");
    RatingsTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    ShopTexture = game.getManager().get("shop.png");
    ShopTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    NoadsTexture = game.getManager().get("noads.png");
    NoadsTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    SoundOnTexture = game.getManager().get("sound_on.png");
    SoundOnTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    SoundOffTexture = game.getManager().get("sound_off.png");
    SoundOffTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    Title = new MenuTextureActor(TitleTexture, 170, 270, 300, 70);
    Play = new MenuTextureActor(PlayTexture, 255, 150, 130, 120);
    Balls = new MenuTextureActor(BallsTexture, 105, 40, 70, 70);
    Ratings = new MenuTextureActor(RatingsTexture, 195, 40, 70, 70);
    Shop = new MenuTextureActor(ShopTexture, 285, 40, 70, 70);
    Noads = new MenuTextureActor(NoadsTexture, 375, 40, 70, 70);
    Sound = new MenuTextureActor(SoundOnTexture, 465, 40, 70, 70);
    if (SoundPrefs.getBoolean("Sound", true) == false) {
        Sound.ChangeTexture(SoundOffTexture);
    }
    stage.addActor(Title);
    stage.addActor(Play);
    stage.addActor(Balls);
    stage.addActor(Ratings);
    stage.addActor(Shop);
    stage.addActor(Noads);
    stage.addActor(Sound);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor((float) (255 / 255.0), (float) (240 / 255.0), (float) (212 / 255.0), 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

    }
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: Convert screen (input) coordinates to world coordinates using `viewport.unproject()`.

Comment: Why are you sleeping the thread when the user presses the play button?

Comment: Thanks! That helped me! But how can I get width and height in world coordinates?

Comment: Width and height are not coordinates. Your actor's width and height are already in world units. Convert your input screenX and screenY to world coordinates, and then you can compare directly to your actor's position and size.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the common issue related to the viewport .for ahndling multiple mobile screen you must use the viewPort. the answer for this question is allready done in the below link please check it once. it will help you to maintain the constants screen ratio for all the devices.

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718125/java-libgdx-keep-actors-position-even-screens-resolution-changes/39946985#39946985
```

please check it once. it may help you. Thank you